# Introducir un mensaje en JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog que contiene JPasswordField

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito encontrar la forma de mostrar un mensaje  en `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog` que **ya** contiene como objeto a `JPasswordField`.

Esto es para un ejercicio de la facultad, donde ya de por sí me estoy excediendo con los recursos utilizados, por lo tanto necesito que la solución se adecue a lo que ya escribí, esto lo aclaro ya que encontré algunas soluciones pero consisten basicamente en rehacer el codigo y emplear objetos tipo JPanel y demás que no vienen al caso. El ejercicio simplemente consistía en crear un Login donde se valide usuario y contraseña mediante el Scanner y la consola de eclipse, algo muy simple, pero yo quería ocultar los caracteres al tipear la contraseña, lo que me llevo a investigar un poco y encontré una solución usando JOptionPane, el ejercicio ya está hecho, lo **único** que faltaría es poder agregar un mensaje donde marco en la imagen que diga "Ingrese contraseña" nada más. Hay alguna forma de hacer eso sin rehacer el código? Gracias de antemano

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código:

```
package ar.edu.ort.cuatri1.tp2;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;

public class Ejercicio7 {

    public static String crearContraseña(Component parent, String title) {
        JPasswordField contraseña = new JPasswordField();

        contraseña.setEchoChar('•');
        contraseña.setColumns(20);

        int returnVal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, contraseña, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION); //aca es donde necesito agregar el mensaje pero en el lugar donde iría este ya está el objeto tipo JPasswordField

        if (returnVal == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
            return new String(contraseña.getPassword());
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

   }


        public static void main (String[] args) {

            String nombreAceptado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Cree su nombre de usuario:", "Sign Up", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            String claveAceptada = null;

            do {
                claveAceptada = crearContraseña(null, "Sign In");
                if (claveAceptada == null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "La contraseña está vacía. Por favor ingrese una contraseña válida", null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);   
                }
            } while(claveAceptada == null);

            String nombreEntrado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su nombre de usuario:"); 
            String claveEntrada = crearContraseña(null, "Ingresar al sistema");
            int i = 1;

            while(nombreEntrado.equals(nombreAceptado) == false || claveEntrada.equals(claveAceptada) == false) {

                if (i == 3) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Su cuenta se ha bloqueado.", null, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Le quedan " + (3 - i) + " intentos restantes", null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    nombreEntrado = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ( "Introduzca nombre de usuario:" );
                    claveEntrada = crearContraseña(null, "Ingresar al sistema");
                    i++;
                }  
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Usted ha accedido con datos de usuario y password correctos. Bienvenido" );     
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pura vida. Tomando en cuenta que JOptionPane.showInputDialog recibe (en este caso), el segundo parámetro como el objeto mensaje, en vez de agregar de forma directa el JPasswordfField, agregar un panel con un JLabel y el campo para la clave. Bajo esa idea modifique el código de la función de la siguiente manera:

```
public static String crearContraseña(Component parent, String title, String message) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JPasswordField contraseña = new JPasswordField();

        contraseña.setEchoChar('•');
        contraseña.setColumns(20);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel(message));
        panel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, contraseña);

        int returnVal = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, title, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if (returnVal == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            return new String(contraseña.getPassword());
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

He agregado un tercer parámetro para poner el mensaje que deseas para el JOptionPane.showInputDialog 
De esta forma quedaría así:

[image: Ejemplo de uso de la función anterior]

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: totalmente!! es justo lo que necesitaba, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda :)